# ios reachability

Tags: ios

is there a possibilty to check whether the iphone is connected via Wlan, via 3g, via 4g or via 2g?! I know there is a reachability class from apple, but with that you can only check if Wlan or wwan...

```
switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        statusString = @"Access Not Available";
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"stop-32.png"] ;
        //Minor interface detail- connectionRequired may return yes, even when the host is unreachable.  We cover that up here...
        connectionRequired= NO;  
        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        statusString = @"Reachable WWAN";
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"WWAN5.png"];
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
         statusString= @"Reachable WiFi";
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Airport.png"];
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cases you're looking to identify belong to the WWAN (Wireless Wide Area Network) case.
There's no official documented way to do this, but [Here's a solution that might do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400340/determining-3g-vs-edge/11400410#11400410) , using private API on the status bar

Comment: Wow, that´s great! Ehm, and am i allowed to use private API´s in my Apps when i want to put it in the apple store?

Comment: Nope, that's why they're called private APIs :(

Comment: So there´s no way to put an app into the store with such kind of analysis?

Comment: You can always give it a try... But I guess not! Even the `UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView` isn't a public class (http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=UIKit.framework&header=UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView.h)

Comment: They are from Apple :'private' means that they don't appear in any *.h (header file) nor any Apple documentation. So People have to come with some techniques to find out about these hidden APIs. The 'limneos' link above goes to a header which isn't from Apple, but was generated by an iOS hacker.