# Is there an iOS library available to compute connection latency and download rate?

Tags: ios

I would like to have an idea of the "network quality" from my app to adapt the user experience.

I know that it is possible to know if connection is WIFI or WWAN (EDGE/3G)... but it seems not possible to make the difference between 3G and edge...

My idea is to "test the connection" by computing latency and download rate.

Before make the library myself, is thee available library for that ?

Of course I need to use "official solution" without using private APIs...

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400340/determining-3g-vs-edge?rq=1

Comment: Agree with your comment but my question whas to know if library or code was available to compute latency and bandwidth... not a hack with private api or screen capture...

Answer (score 1):

There's no lib AFAIK, because it's a very complex problem. If you were to only calculate the download speed, how would you compare this to the app responsiveness ? The latter is eventually what is important to the user; download speed is only one factor in a more complex equation. Also, how would you react to temporary network disruptions or slugginess ? (fairly common on Mobile network), they do not necessarily imply a fallback onto lighter images..

It's a pandora's box in my view. I'd tend to design an app for the worst case scenario if I were you. Small images, compatible with good view quality, and bullet proof user-notifications when the ISO stack says that something went wrong (timeout, wrong url, no response from server etc...), meaningful transitions from low pic to high pic res, ability to cancel an ongoing request, progress bars etc..

When the user is notified about what's going on, he/she will avoid/understand edge cases situations, and will not blame on the app if something goes wrong.

Now, if you want to address the app performance paradigm, I've started to look into https://newrelic.com/docs/site/apdex (I have no stake into their business, it's provided as an option with my MBaas). Seems there are good things, but I haven't integrated any of their features yet.

good luck !