# Objective-C determine data network type of the iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, internet-connection, cellular-network

Im on an application that receive data from server, the problem is when user connect to `cellular data` (Not `3G` or `WIFI`), it take ages to receive data.

i had implemented this code from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127014/1091539) but im not sure if it is effective or not, sometimes it's giving me an accurate type, and sometimes it don't.

here is my code:

```
- (void)newtworkType {

NSArray *subviews = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"]subviews];
NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}

switch ([[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"]integerValue]) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"No wifi or cellular");
        break;

    case 1:
        NSLog(@"2G");
        break;

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"3G");
        break;

    case 3:
        NSLog(@"4G");
        break;

    case 4:
        NSLog(@"LTE");
        break;

    case 5:
        NSLog(@"Wifi");
        break;


    default:
        break;
}}
```

is this the best i can do??, i tried [Apple Reachability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), but it can determine if `reachabilityForInternetConnection` or just `reachabilityForLocalWiFi` but that not helpfull in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working fine but I think its private api so may be apple rejected. Can you please give me suggestion do you upload app on apple store and approved by apple? please comment so I can move forward to upload my app on store. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Crashes on iPhone X.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that the `Status bar` is not hidden in your application.
if it's not visible it will always return `No wifi or cellular` because your code reads the text in the `Status bar` thats all.

this is the best way to solve your problem, just make the `Status bar` not hidden then the application will get the text about the network type.

Comment: i didnt think a moment that if the status bar is set to hidden will cause not reading the value, thank you a million

Comment: @Atrash its working fine but I think its private api so may be apple rejected. Can you please give me suggestion do you upload app on apple store and approved by apple? please comment so I can move forward to upload my app on store. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 29):

if using `iOS 7`+ then you can get information from `CoreTelephony` framework following method :

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
NSLog(@"Current Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
```

Possibles values defined  which you will get are as follows :
`CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS`, `CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge` ,`CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA` , `CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE`   etc

Comment: this is the actual answer, the rest is hackery, which can stop working any time

Comment: Docs say it was available starting in iOS 4: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: But `currentRadioAccessTechnology` is available starting in iOS7 . @BrianColavito

Comment: @muzz currentRadioAccessTechnology returns always CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge even I change wifi to cellular data. any idea regarding?

Answer (score 0):

case 1, with the `NSLog(@"2G");` is the case where the phone is on regular cellular data, not 3G, not 4G, and not WiFi.

What you should do is insert code below the NSLog for 2G to prevent the data transfer.

Comment: Is this the best way i can do it ?

Comment: As far was I know, yes? As for you requesting more detail (in the bounty), you would need to tell us how to prevent your "data transfer." Since we don't have that code, we can't actually help you.