# How to get the current active network type (wifi or 3G) of iPhone, without using the Reachability class

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

In my case, I can not use the `Reachability` class, because I am using iPhone in a wifi network which can not access the internet. It's just an **intranet** wifi.

That means, the `Reachability` class will return `Not Reachable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 -(void)newtworkType {

 NSArray *subviews = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"]subviews];
NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}


switch ([[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"]integerValue]) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"No wifi or cellular");
        break;

    case 1:
        NSLog(@"2G");
        break;

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"3G");
        break;

    case 3:
        NSLog(@"4G");
        break;

    case 4:
        NSLog(@"LTE");
        break;

    case 5:
        NSLog(@"Wifi");
        break;


    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: @DevinZhao it maybe use private APIs , as this posts says:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400340/determining-3g-vs-edge/11400410#11400410

Comment: Yes, this is definitely private. I'd be curious to know: has anyone been able to get his app on the Store using that? Also, keep in mind that Apple's implementation may change, this code relies heavily on a specific Status Bar's view hierarchy. If it ever changes, this code will make your app crash.

Answer (score 0):

For your `intranet wifi` I think you can also use `Reachability`

You only need to change the host name to your intranet host.

Such as :

```
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;
int s;
ip4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip4addr.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.1", &ip4addr.sin_addr);

s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&ip4addr, sizeof ip4addr);

Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&ip4addr];
```

above code is wrote by faildrop , https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/issues/6

I do not test , but I think it can deal with your problem