# Check if Internet is available including 4G

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check if my user has internet available to perform certain tasks such as log in to their user account. I'm currently using the reachability class that *used* to work but now it only works to check if there's a wifi connection. If my phone is connected to 4G or mobile data, it'll say that there is no internet connection. Is there another way I can check for internet connection?

Thanks for your help in advance! :-)

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family:0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
    let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

    return isReachable && !needsConnection
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx)

Comment: ^ that method uses the reachability class that i mentioned in my post. Unfortunately, when I use that class, it only detects WiFi and does not detect 4G...

Comment: You edited your post and added in the `Reachability` part subsequent to me posting a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19378112/4475605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new Swift File and Include this class :-

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

      var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
      zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
      zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

      guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
           SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
      }) else {
          return false
      }

      var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
      if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
          return false
      }  

      let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
      let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
      return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
   }
 }
```

Then you can check connectivity in another class like

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() { 
  //Has Connectivity
} else {
  //No connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```